# Symfony Doctrine ORM ManyToMany - blog with tags - i dont get all tags from blog, without lazy load

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

> Doctrine lazy loading on manyToMany.

I'm using `Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag` in my blog(post).

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"} )
     * @ORM\JoinTable( name="blog__post_tag" , 
     * joinColumns={ @ORM\JoinColumn( name="blog_post_id", referencedColumnName="id" )},
     * inverseJoinColumns={ @ORM\JoinColumn( name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id" )}
     * )
     */
    private $tags;
```

Working code:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('p')
                ->innerJoin('p.tags', 't')
                ->where('t = :name')->setParameter('name', $tag)
                ->andWhere('p.isActive = :active')->setParameter('active', TRUE)
                ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC');
        return $q->getQuery();
```

From this output query i use tags in twig. So i have to select post and tags. If i update the code to :

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('p', 't')
                ->innerJoin('p.tags', 't')
                ->where('t = :name')->setParameter('name', $tag)
                ->andWhere('p.isActive = :active')->setParameter('active', TRUE)
                ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC');
        return $q->getQuery();
```

I get only one tag.

INFO :

- Working code uses more db query (1 more query).
- Updated code works (no more query). But in result i get **only one tag** for all post.

**Example :**

- "My First post " has tags ['one','two','three'].
- "My Second post " has tags ['two'].

When i use first query. Works fine. But the doctrine lazy load code for tags. I get output for (query1) **two** = "My First post " has tags ['one','two','three']. , "My Second post " has tags ['two'].

When i use second query. The output for (query2) **two** = "My First post " has tags ['two']. , "My Second post " has tags ['two'].

> I need all tags from the post. Currently i get only one tag form the post.

Answer (score 1):

It's like that because of INNER JOIN. Great answer about join types is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/919567

This version of query will work for you:

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p', 't')
    ->leftJoin('p.tags', 't')
    ->where('t = :name')->setParameter('name', $tag)
    ->andWhere('p.isActive = :active')->setParameter('active', TRUE)
    ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC');

return $q->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudhakar K, you should definitely use the answer of Pawel if this work for you - I doubt it would, but still.

The thing here is you cannot achieve the result you're looking for in less than 2 requests, because you're trying to do 2 things at the same time:

1. Find all `Post` entities related to a specific `Tag`
2. Find all `Tag` entities related to found `Post` entities

... and all that with the same join, which seems outright impossible. Since you impose a conditions on the `Tag` you want to retrieve, the only retrieved `Tag` entities will be the ones that fulfill that condition, meaning the one `Tag` that has the name you searched.

You would have to do multiple joins to the same table for this to work, and even then I doubt it would work the way you want.

Keep in mind that Doctrine was more designed for ease-of-use than for performance. Trying to prevent a low-cost, single additional request in this manner is counterproductive when using Doctrine IMHO.

Knowing that, I strongly recommend that you use your first solution.

Comment: Hey Zephyr, can you point me to part in query where Sudhakar is finding all `Tag` entities related to found `Post`?

Comment: Well, he's not, according to his DQL request. But according to his question, it's what he tries to do.